# How do I create a contant managed list of linked images and display it as a block?

Tags: views, blocks

On the homepage of the site I'm making I need to have a few CTAs (calls to action) linking to products in the shop, which is running Drupal Commerce. The CTAs comprise of:

- An image
- A link title
- A URL to a product display node
- A limit of 2 CTAs

Is there any way I can do this using Views 3 (I'm guessing that would be the best way, please correct me otherwise) without writing my own module? I only have  a very basic understanding of writing modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go down the views route as it will be the simplest. Just set the filters to only return products that have images and limit the view to output 2 items max. You could add an extra field onto the product content type that you then check for in views to allow the admin to control which products get sent to this block.

Comment: There is a little problem with that, the images on the CTAs are not the same as the images on the product, they are advertisements. Add a new image field to the product? Sorry if this is obvious, I'm still very new to Drupal in general.